# POST controller- Value is binding as null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

net and my code has various part. First the model.
where data is like this

```
public string skuItem { get; set; }
```

Then I am using chtml where I am using

```
<table id="submissionTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample ID</td>
            <td>Additional Comments</td>
            <td>Acid-stable amino acids</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr id="tablerow0">
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="skuItem[0]" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="skuItem[0]" cols="20" rows="5" class="form-control" style="border-radius: 12px;" />
                <span asp-validation-for="skuItem[0]" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</p>
```

script for adding other line is working

```
<script>
    var counter = 1;

    $(function () {
        $('#add').click(function () {
            $('<tr id="tablerow' + counter + '"><td>' +
                '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="skuItem[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +

                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeTr(' + counter + ');">Delete</button>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>'
            ).appendTo('#submissionTable');
            
            counter++;
            return false;
        });
    });
    
    function removeTr(index) {
        if (counter > 1) {
            $('#tablerow' + index).remove();
            counter--;
        }
    
        return false;
    }


    Ladda.bind('.btn', { timeout: 1000 });
</script>
```

MY ajax function is like this

function SubmitAddEdit(form) {

```
if ($(form).valid()) {
    var data = $(form).serializeArray();

    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiurl,
        data: data ,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                popup.modal('hide');
                toastr.success(data.message);
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            } else {
                toastr.error(data.message)
            }
        }
    });
}

return false;
```

}

[Till this point think is working check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAG66.png)

Once ajax is executed post controller is giving value as null

[please check this controller where there is 4 count but somehow skuItem is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZy3.png)

please guide me why my code has error, specially when javascript can have value but at time of ajax post i am getting null in controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostPurchaseItems([FromBody] List<PurchaseItems> purchase)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            try
            {

                if (purchase[0].purchaseItemsId == Guid.Empty)
                    {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= purchase.Count; i++)

                        {

                        ApplicationUser appUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

                        purchase[0].purchaseId = Guid.NewGuid();
                        purchase[0].CreatedById = appUser.Id;
                        purchase[0].CreatedByName = appUser.FullName;
                        purchase[0].CreateBy = appUser.FullName;
                        purchase[0].CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
                        purchase[0].DeleteFlag = 0;


                  




                    _context.PurchaseItems.Add(purchase[0]);

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                        }

                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Add new data success." });
                }
                else
                {

                    ApplicationUser appUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                    purchase[0].CreatedById = appUser.Id;
                    purchase[0].CreatedByName = appUser.FullName;
                    purchase[0].CreateBy = appUser.FullName;
                    purchase[0].CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
                    
                   

                    List<Contact> contact = _context.Contact.Where(x => x.customerId.Equals(purchase[0].customerId) && x.DeleteFlag != 1).ToList();

                    


                    _context.Update(purchase);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();






                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Edit data success." });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
            }


        
               
            }
```

Comment: please paste the code of your controller

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul I already edit it Thanks!

Comment: Since the parameter you are accepting in your controller action is named purchase so the data object which you are sending from your ajax must contain an array named purchase. Your issue is probably happening because the data in your ajax probably does not have an array named purchase. Also I am sure the solution to this problem already exists on stackoverflow so its best if you delete your question.

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the name should be in this format: `list[index].property`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="skuItem" name="purchase[0].skuItem" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="skuItem" name="purchase[0].skuItem" cols="20" rows="5" class="form-control" style="border-radius: 12px;" />
    <span asp-validation-for="skuItem" name="purchase[0].skuItem" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Second, the json string is not match the `List<PurchaseItems>` structure. You can send it using the default contentType.

```
var data = $(form).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: apiurl,
    data: data ,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            popup.modal('hide');
            toastr.success(data.message);
            dataTable.ajax.reload();
        } else {
            toastr.error(data.message)
        }
    }
});
```

Also modify the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostPurchaseItems(List<PurchaseItems> purchase)
```